# Are "large" try blocks not as performant as smaller ones for some reason?

Tags: .net, performance, exception, try-catch

I read something that I didn't understand:

"Avoid having try blocks with excessive amounts of code, especially if the throwing code isn’t immediately related or dependent on it. This is because large code bodies (in both methods and blocks) can preemptively disable at runtime optimizations made by the Just In Time compiler (JIT)."
https://www.hexacta.com/2017/02/03/advanced-exceptions-in-net/

Is this suggesting I shouldn't have long methods, because some compiler optimizations can't be made?  Or it is suggesting I shouldn't wrap, for example, a large section of code that represents a thread loop inside of one big try block, and should use a bunch of smaller ones instead? Obviously, correctness is more important as far as error handling goes, but what does all this mean?

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting one because I was always of the belief that the overhead of throwing and handling an exception is much higher than trapping the error preemptively. I guess as the VM is having to unwind the stack and so on whenever you have an exception.

So, once you've thrown the exception (which has taken a long time) what does it matter if you have a decent amount of exception-handling code in the catch (or finally) blocks? I'm watching this one with interest.

Comment: They're not saying don't have a lot of code in the catch block, after the exception has been thrown. They're saying don't have one monolithic try block that has all your code in it. Instead, if you've got 2 or 3 different calls that can throw exceptions, put them each in their own try blocks, so you're just handling that one condition. Sometimes doing so or not doing so is necessary for correctness. Often, I find that doing so makes rethrowing the exception easier and clearer, because it has a much more specific cause in terms of what the application was trying to do.